# C++ multimap lookup failing

Tags: c++, dictionary, multimap

I am using a multimap to store objects which encode atomic reactions. The multimap looks something like this:

```cpp
std::multimap<ReactionElement, ReactionElement> reaction_map;
```

The keys are the reactants and the values are the products. I then encounter a situation where I find two reactant atoms and I can look up in the map what possible products those reactants can form.

The essentials of the ReactionElements class look something like this:

```cpp
class ReactionElement {

  friend bool operator==(const ReactionElement& lhs, const ReactionElement& rhs);
  friend bool operator<(const ReactionElement& lhs, const ReactionElement& rhs);

public:
  // Some methods here ...

private:
  // The Atom class tracks the element
  Atom atom_a;
  Atom atom_b;

  // SiteSpecies and NeighborSpecies classes track the reaction geometry
  SiteSpecies site_species_a;
  NeighborSpecies neighbor_species_b;

  // int members track reaction energetics
  int e_initial, e_transition, e_final;

  double reac_distance;

}; // ReactionElement
```

I read a bunch of ReactionElement-ReactionElement pairs from a file and insert each into the multimap.

Here's the problem: when I go to retrieve them, only some of the reactions are accessible. For some reactions, I can call reaction_map.find(reactant) and get nothing. However, I can iterate across the multimap and I see all of the pairs that I inserted. I used this as a basic diagnostic:

```cpp
for(multimap<ReactionElement, ReactionElement>::iterator it = reaction_map.begin();
    it != reaction_map.end(); ++it)
  std::cout << reaction_map.count(it->first) << '\n';
```

This printed a handful of ones, twos, and *zeros*. How is this possible?

Any thoughts?

(EDIT) The comparison operators are detailed below. I am fairly certain that each of the member classes is well-ordered. I will confirm.

```
// This directly compares each member (using a tolerance of .01 for reac_distance).
bool operator==(const ReactionElement& lhs, const ReactionElement& rhs) {
  return (lhs.atom_a == rhs.atom_a and lhs.atom_b == rhs.atom_b and
      lhs.site_species_a == rhs.site_species_a and
      lhs.neighbor_species_b == rhs.neighbor_species_b and
      lhs.e_initial == rhs.e_initial and lhs.e_transition == rhs.e_transition and
      lhs.e_final == rhs.e_final and
      fabs(lhs.hop_distance-rhs.hop_distance) <= 0.01);
}

// < orders on members in the order they appear in the class definition.
bool operator<(const ReactionElement& lhs, const ReactionElement& rhs) {
  if (lhs.atom_a < rhs.atom_a)
    return true;
  else if (lhs.atom_a == rhs.atom_a and lhs.atom_b < rhs.atom_b) 
    return true;
  else if (lhs.atom_a == rhs.atom_a and lhs.atom_b == rhs.atom_b and 
           lhs.site_species_a < rhs.site_species_a)
    return true;
  // etc for the remaining members.

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Please also post the implementation of `==`, `<`

Comment: Are you sure that your implementation of `operator<` provides a [strict weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) required by `multimap`?

Comment: Your less than is buggy. You my use: `std::tie(lhs.a,lhs.b,lhs.c) < std::tie(rhs.a,rhs.b,rhs.c)`

Comment: Notice that your comparison operators also use the operators for Atom, SiteSpecies and NeighborSpecies, which are objects. So they also need == and < operators implemented respecting strict weak ordering. Do you have these? If so, please post their code also.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I've found the bugs. There was some faulty logic in the NeighborSpecies < operator that seems to have been causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between iteration and `count` / `find` is that `count` and `find` have to compare elements (iteration does not). Per default, `std::multimap` uses `std::less` for comparison. This is equivalent to `<`. `std::multimap` requires this relation to be a [strict weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). This implies esp. the following rules:

- `!(x < x)`
- if `(x < y)`, then `!(y < x)`

Make sure that your `operator<` implementation meets these rules. If not, change it, or provide a custom `Comparator` for the `std::multimap`.